# Pseudo-range computing

Tags: distance, gps, satellite, position

I have to compute the relative pseudo-range for my student job, unfortunately, nobody can help me because they are not read into the topic enough. So I'm asking here:

My receiver has to have a 1500 bit buffer, so all 5 subframes are found and decoded. This works just fine. I have a buffer counter (`num_bits_buffered`), which counts after all subframes are decoded until 1500 new bits are found in the buffer.

Another module provides the code phase of the signal.

The Receiver has a function `get_TOT(decoder, code_phase)` providing the corrected time of transmission.

And here, my first problem occurred: the toc and toe of one satellite were one bit lower - causing the satellite to have a completely different time (16 sec difference). Therefore, it was useless for pseudo-range computing. Do I have to correct the clock time for the pseudo-range computing too?

Now to the main part:
I tried the following formula for pseudo-range computing (All variables unitless):

```
T_s = TOW * 6 + num_bits_buffered_s / DataFrequency(GPSL1) + code_phase_s / CodeFrequency(GPSL1)
P_s = (T_s - T_1) * c
```

I get values close to the real ones(+- 2 km), compared to the measure of the distance between my provided position and the computed satellite positions (the one SV with other toc excluded). If I use my PVT algorithm on the pseudo-range data, I'm 1.5km off in a different directions.

Is anybody here seeing my mistake?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: are you sure this is a GIS problem?